# How to get works ViewChildren with NgTemplateOutlet? (4.0.0-rc1)

Tags: angular

I Would like to get children created with NgTemplateOutlet.

I have this [example plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/BHZHcVKuhoP8OzQHIxAR/), where I have Child component and Parent Component, Parent has an input template that renders using ngTemplateOutlet:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <div>parent</div>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template1"></ng-container>
    <div *ngFor="let child of children; let i = index">{{i}}</div>
    {{children.length}}    
`
})
export class Parent {
  @Input() template1; 
  children = [];
  @ViewChildren(Child) viewList: QueryList<Child>;

  updateElements() {
    setTimeout(() => this.children = this.viewList.toArray());
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.viewList.changes.subscribe(() => this.updateElements());
    this.updateElements();
  }      
}
```

Parent component try to get `Child` children using `ViewChildren` but don't works.

Someone knows how to get work it?

In the other hand I have wrote [other plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wFvjrJjNYBLx5sYnJRhm?p=preview) where I'm using ngFor to render several Child components and it works.

Since both, ngFor and ngTemplateOutlet, using `viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView` I think two ways should work the same way.

Why not?

PS: I have using Angular 4.0.0-rc1, but I think is the same for Angular 2.x

Answer (score -2):

In the meantime you could use workaround injecting parent into child.

Comment: Until I understand, Child components on appcomponent get injector from parent... then they received the appcomponent injector, then Angular can not inject Parent component.

Comment: It is actually not that obvious, the problem is that `createEmbeddedView` does not take injector as parameter, it leads to another question, why template parent injector is inherited from component that defines template? Looks like limitation/bug to me, it should be configurable. And i think it explains why `ViewChildren`/`ContentChildren` do not work.

Comment: Ops, i have just to see your issue. Ok, let me know if you have some respone.

Comment: @kemsky further more explanation could be very useful